# Group the GROUP BY results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I have a query:

```
Select 
    (coalesce(sum(Ledger.Debit), 0) - coalesce(sum(Ledger.Credit), 0))   
    + Accounts.PreviousBalance  [Balance] 
FROM 
    Accounts
LEFT join 
    Ledger on Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
Where 
    Accounts.Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY 
    Accounts.ID, Accounts.PreviousBalance
```

and it returns 23 rows of all accounts summary that how much client has to **pay**(-ve) and to **receive**(+ve) for each account:

```
Balance
=========
800655.00
1869213.50
-6365.25
1148160.00
145743.70
804225.00
157625.00
66440.00
972950.00
780063.50
646680.75
277761.00
347100.00
-70882.50
-7435.50
431940.00
1319340.00
245685.00
372400.00
158220.00
608108.00
6777029.00
1147920.00
```

Now I want to have a summary of this summary. How much to pay and receive cumulative values. E.g.:

```
Summary
===========
-84683.25      //sum of all negative values
19077259.45    //sum of all positive values
```

I did it like this:

```
SELECT SUM([Balance]) as [Summary]
From 
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN [Balance] > 0 THEN 'Receieve' ELSE 'Pay' END AS 'Type', [Balance]
    From 
    (
        SELECT --Accounts.ID,
            -- ( Debit - Credit ) + Previous balance = balance
        (coalesce(sum(Ledger.Debit), 0) - coalesce(sum(Ledger.Credit), 0))   
        + Accounts.PreviousBalance  [Balance]
        FROM Accounts
        LEFT join Ledger ON Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
        WHERE Accounts.Status = 'Active'
        GROUP BY Accounts.ID, Accounts.PreviousBalance
    ) as accountsSummary
) as summary
GROUP BY [Type]
```

But I know this is not the good and optimize way. It is some messy nested sub queries approach. There must be a cleaner or better way do it. How can achieve it with a better approach?

Comment: You should have a look at [CTE's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Is it more optimize than a sub query? Because it also creates a temp table a sub query does.

Comment: Why don't you profile the two and look at the difference.  There probably will not be any performance difference in this case though.  I just find the CTE's reads better and are clearer in their intent.

Comment: Yeah CTE looks a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
WITH Balances
AS (
    SELECT 
        (coalesce(sum(Ledger.Debit), 0) - coalesce(sum(Ledger.Credit), 0)) + Accounts.PreviousBalance  [Balance] 
    FROM 
        Accounts
    LEFT join 
        Ledger on Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
    Where 
        Accounts.Status = 'Active'
    GROUP BY 
        Accounts.ID, Accounts.PreviousBalance
),
Receipts AS (
    SELECT SUM(Balance) Balance
    FROM Balances
    WHERE Balance > 0
),
Payments AS (
    SELECT SUM(Balance) Balance
    FROM Balances
    WHERE Balance < 0
)    
SELECT Balance FROM Receipts 
UNION 
SELECT Balance FROM Payments
```

Comment: It says `Invalid object name 'Reciepts'`. Sorry I never used CTE other wise would have solved the error myself.

Comment: Looks like valid syntax to me.   And a nice approach.  +1  But he TSQL from the OP may be more efficient.

Comment: @Shaharyar - Spelling mistake ;)

Comment: Yup I figured it out. Embarrassed I couldn't judge it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i like the naming convention of CTE's

Answer (score 1):

In outer query just differentiate *positive* values and *negative* values in `group by` that's all you need

```
WITH Balances
AS (
    SELECT 
        (coalesce(sum(Ledger.Debit), 0) - coalesce(sum(Ledger.Credit), 0)) + Accounts.PreviousBalance  [Balance] 
    FROM 
        Accounts
    LEFT join 
        Ledger on Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
    Where 
        Accounts.Status = 'Active'
    GROUP BY 
        Accounts.ID, Accounts.PreviousBalance
),
select SUM(Balance)
from Balances
group by case when Balance < 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: I didn't know `GROUP BY` also has `CASE`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use LINQ. First get whole crunch of data using SQL. And then Query it using c# (using LINQ). It will be much easier.